# Rotation in Unity3D

Tags: rotation, transform, unity-game-engine, euler-angles

This is a simplified code from what I'm trying to do:

```
var angle = 1.57;
if ( this.transform.rotation.y > angle ){
  this.transform.rotation.y--;
} else if ( this.transform.rotation.y < angle ){
  this.transform.rotation.y++;
}
```

I'm used to code in AS3, and if I do that in flash, it works perfectly, though in Unity3D it doesn't, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why, or how could I get that effect.

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

edit:

my object is a rigidbody car with 2 capsule colliders driving in a "bumpy" floor, and at some point he just loses direction precision, and I think its because of it's heirarchical rotation system.

(thanks to kay for the transform.eulerAngles tip)

Comment: Did you know that Unity has its own dedicated [Stack Exchange website](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html])? You may have more dedicated answers there.

Comment: Technically, answers.unity3d.com isn't a Stack Exchange member.  It's provided by Qato, and open source clone.  But yes, there is a dedicated community support site for Unity there.

Comment: I agree it's a pretty good and very valuable resource, and I'm posting there from time to time but I don't like their reputation system: An accepted answer is worth 0 points. Maybe a bit childish but spending every day 15 minutes something on answering is little bit like the game I'm developing :-)

Comment: Unity is not called Unity3D.  Your second if statement is unnecessary because you're dealing with floats.  Your code results in non-normalized quaternions, which are not acceptable as rotation values.

Answer (score 12):

`transform.rotation` retrieves a [Quaternion](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html). Try `transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y` instead.

Comment: actually I did, but the object is a rigidbody car with 2 capsule colliders driving in a "bumpy" floor, and at some point he just loses direction precision, and I think its because of it's heirarchical rotation system... I'm adding this information to the question so people can see it better.

Comment: Did you try transform.localRotation?

Answer (score 3):

Transform Rotation is used for setting an angle, not turning an object, so you would need to get the rotation, add your change, and then set the new rotation.

Try using transform.rotate instead.

Check the Unity3d scripting reference here:
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems so far. First the hierarchical rotation of Unity. Based on what you are trying to achieve you should manipulate either

```
transform.localEulerAngles
or
transform.eulerAngles
```

The second thing is, you can't modify the euler angles this way, as the Vectors are all passed by value:

```
transform.localEulerAngles.y--;
```

You have to do it this way:

```
Vector3 rotation = transform.localEulerAngles;
rotation.y--;
transform.localEulerAngles = rotation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Quaternion Object

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler ( transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y++, transform.rotation.z );

You can also use transform.Rotate function.

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestion to use transform.Rotate( ) is probably what you're going to need to do to actually make it rotate, BUT the variables of transform.Rotate( ) are velocity/speed rather than direction, so transform.Rotate( ) will have to use more than one axis if you want an angled rotation. Ex:

```
class Unity // Example is in C#
{
    void Update( )
    {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

This will rotate the object around its y-axis at a speed of 1.

Let me know if this helps - and if it hinders I can explain it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You should try multiplyng your rotation factor with `Time.deltaTime`

Hope that helps

Peace

Answer (score 0):

Here is my script for GameObject rotation with touch

```
//
//  RotateController.cs
//
//  Created by Ramdhan Choudhary on 12/05/13.
//

using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class RotateController
{

        private float RotationSpeed = 9.5f;
        private const float mFingerDistanceEpsilon = 1.0f;
        public float MinDist = 2.0f;
        public float MaxDist = 50.0f;
        private Transform mMoveObject = null;
        private bool isEnabledMoving = false;


        //************** Rotation Controller Constructor **************//
        public RotateController (Transform goMove)
        {
                isEnabledMoving = true;
                mMoveObject = goMove;
                if (mMoveObject == null) {
                        Debug.LogWarning ("Error! Cannot find object!");
                        return;
                }
        }

        //************** Handle Object Rotation **************//
        public void Update ()
        {
                if (!isEnabledMoving && mMoveObject != null) {
                        return;
                }

                Vector3 camDir = Camera.main.transform.forward;
                Vector3 camLeft = Vector3.Cross (camDir, Vector3.down);

                // rotate
                if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
                        mMoveObject.Rotate (camLeft, Input.touches [0].deltaPosition.y * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
                        mMoveObject.Rotate (Vector3.down, Input.touches [0].deltaPosition.x * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
                }


        }
}
```